# What do we call the entire project which is based on arranged kinetic actions?

Tags: word-request, word-usage, terminology

I love that concept whenever any company comes up with it as a part of their marketing campaign but not sure what do we call such action.

The action starts with one tiny thing (say striking a small metal ball) and it hits another thing that swings further and does some action. The beauty continues and finally a big gate may open showing some message/greetings. So, a small tiny ball to a giant gate everything happens kinetically.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIGyVa5Xftw) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_P0yZlhVQ4) are two videos showing the action which is brilliantly crafted. I know the word ***'[chain reaction](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/chain-reaction)'*** but I've always used, heard and seen the phrase in a different context. Even the dictionary uses an example that does not fit to my concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the United States, at least, such a machine or device can be called a [Rube Goldberg Machine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) Another term is Chain Reaction Machine or Device. One that involves a rolling ball can be called [Rolling Ball Scuplture.](http://www.waymarking.com/cat/details.aspx?f=1&guid=439f3ce3-d220-428d-9a1f-7c76620a27d9&exp=True) A popular term for a mechanical chain reaction is [domino effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_effect), which can also literally be incorporated into a Rube Goldberg Machine.

In the broader sense, a Rube Goldberg Machine means a

> deliberately over-engineered or overdone to perform a very simple task in a very complicated fashion. (wikipedia)

The term has come to refer to the more narrowly defined machine/device that does rely on "arranged kinetic reactions."

Even popular entertainment uses the term Rube Goldberg Machine. For example, the console/PC game Fallout 3 contains a store called Gold Ribbon Grocers, which is booby-trapped with a device called Rube Goldberg Machine. A vide of the Fallout 3 Rube Goldberg Machine is here. It relies on both the mechanical domino effect and chemical reactions. See [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVaLHlNICx8).

MIT stages a Chain Reaction Machine event each Friday after Thanksgiving but does not use the term Rube Goldberg Machine.