# What is the name of this thing in English?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the name of the thing where objects are well connected and pass through different sections to finally help do one thing at the end in a creative way. Where an object moves along a specific path, hits another which has a new path which moves along and hits another etc? :)

Comment: _Contraption_ might be suitable.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ve4M4UsJQo) might be one of the most famous ones (at least recently), made entirely from car parts.

Comment: [Related question and answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35484/what-do-we-call-the-entire-project-which-is-based-on-arranged-kinetic-actions/35496)

Answer (score 11):

A 'Rube Goldberg machine'?

Here are some examples of what I think you might be talking about.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFWHbRApS3c

(The name comes from the cartoonist Rube Goldberg, who would draw cartoons of fanciful and intricate inventions like these.)

Comment: Another example is in the [introduction to the TV show Elementary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JT3iMzS4k).

Comment: +1 The British equivalent of Rube Goldberg was [Heath Robinson](http://www.design-facility.com/blog/mad-inventors-ridiculous-machinery/).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice – once for the answer, and once for the link to the very cool video!

Answer (score 2):

You can coin your own.

*Chain Reaction, Serial Chain Reactors, Chain Impulse Transmitters, Serial  Momentons ..*

or even

*`Domino Chain`*

Answer (score 1):

A Rube Goldberg machine.

It is a machine that goes through complicated and unnecessary processes to complete a simple task.
Example: Task: to dump dog food in a bowl. Start: a phone vibrating when it receives a phone call, knocking down a set of dominos.

Wikipedia: A Rube Goldberg machine is a contraption, invention, device or apparatus that is deliberately over-engineered or overdone to perform a very simple task in a very complicated fashion, usually including a chain reaction. The expression is named after American cartoonist and inventor Rube Goldberg (1883–1970).